# I am trying to open a file in Sublime Text through CreateProcess() but the build shows errors

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

```
STARTUPINFO         siStartupInfo;
PROCESS_INFORMATION piProcessInfo;

memset(&siStartupInfo, 0, sizeof(siStartupInfo));
memset(&piProcessInfo, 0, sizeof(piProcessInfo));

siStartupInfo.cb = sizeof(siStartupInfo);

if (CreateProcess("C:\\Program Files\\SublimeText2\\sublime_text",              
   " source.cpp",                       
    NULL,
    NULL,
    FALSE,
    CREATE_DEFAULT_ERROR_MODE,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    &siStartupInfo,
    &piProcessInfo) == FALSE)


    WaitForSingleObject(piProcessInfo.hProcess, INFINITE);


::CloseHandle(piProcessInfo.hThread);
::CloseHandle(piProcessInfo.hProcess);
```

I am trying to open a file in Sublime Text through `CreateProcess` but the build shows the following errors:

1. > argument of type "const char *" is incompatible with parameter of type "LPWSTR".
2. > argument of type "const char *" is incompatible with parameter of type "LPWCSTR" .
3. > 'BOOL CreateProcessW(LPCWSTR,LPWSTR,LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES,LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES,BOOL,DWORD,LPVOID,LPCWSTR,LPSTARTUPINFOW,LPPROCESS_INFORMATION)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'const char [32]' to 'LPCWSTR' .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`LPWSTR` (**L**ong **P**ointer to **W**ide **STR**ing) is a `wchar_t*`, not a `char*`. You have 3 options to fix the problem:

1. Don't compile with `UNICODE` #defined.
2. Use `CreateProcessA`
3. Change the call to use wide string constants, and call the `W` version of the function explicitly, as in:

   ```
   CreateProcessW(L"C:\\Program Files\\SublimeText2\\sublime_text", 
                 //...
   ```

Of the three, the third option is the one you should use.

Comment: above helped work . Could you please tell a way to terminate the App(Sublime Text) after a given time using the above code .

Comment: @theB: Third option should call `CreateProcessW`, since you are passing explicit wide character string literals. The compatible character string type for `CreateProcess` is `TCHAR*`, and using the generic-text mappings isn't all the rage any more, I hear. Besides, you cannot pass a string literal to the second parameter of `CreateProcessW`. It is required to be a writable buffer.

Comment: @IInspectable - yep you're absolutely right. I always jumble CreateProcess and ShellExecute. I'll edit in a bit.

Comment: Also worth noting: If you pass both an application name and command line argument to `CreateProcess`, the application will get the command line as specified. In the general case this means that the target process will skip over the first argument, assuming that it holds the executable image, and start parsing arguments starting with the second. In this case, however, there is no second command line argument. General guideline: Only ever pass both arguments if you have a specific need (i.e. an application that expects all command line arguments to be arguments). This is rare.