# Error events when CreateProcess uses a path: E0167 argument of type "char *" is incompatible with parameter of type "LPWSTR"

Tags: c++, winapi, createprocess

When I use the CreateProcess command in C++ VisualStudio 2017, I give a error about LPWSTR: 
E0167   argument of type "char *" is incompatible with parameter of type "LPWSTR".

How can I fix it? 
The bellow code is part of my code about the problem.
Thanks for any your suggestion.

```
int main()
{
...
    ConnectToEngine("stockfish.exe");
...
}


void ConnectToEngine(char* path)
{
    pipin_w = pipin_r = pipout_w = pipout_r = NULL;
    sats.nLength = sizeof(sats);
    sats.bInheritHandle = TRUE;
    sats.lpSecurityDescriptor = NULL;

    CreatePipe(&pipout_r, &pipout_w, &sats, 0);
    CreatePipe(&pipin_r, &pipin_w, &sats, 0);

    sti.dwFlags = STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW | STARTF_USESTDHANDLES;
    sti.wShowWindow = SW_HIDE;
    sti.hStdInput = pipin_r;
    sti.hStdOutput = pipout_w;
    sti.hStdError = pipout_w;

    CreateProcess(NULL, path, NULL, NULL, TRUE, 0, NULL, NULL, &sti, &pi);
}
```

Comment: You need a parameter of _`LPWSTR`_ and not `char*`, what's unclear about the error message?

Comment: As you can see here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/Intl/windows-data-types-for-strings `LPWSTR` is a `typedef` for `unsigned wchar_t*`, not `char*`

Comment: I did it:
 char* exename[] = "stockfish.exe";
 ConnectToEngine("exename");
but it dosn't work.
error: E0520 initialization with '{...}' expected for aggregate object

Comment: @nanosi Just look at the defintiion of `LPWSTR`, it's not a `char*`, a corresponding raw string literal is prefixed with `L`.

Comment: This is related to you enabling `UNICODE` in your project settings. With that said you most likely want to do the fix that @πάνταῥεῖ told you. Also use `wchar_t*` instead of `char*`.

Comment: Thank you for your patient @ drescherjm, @πάντα ῥεῖ, @ UnholySheep .
I fixed it by these changes:


int main()
{..
wchar_t a[] = L"stockfish.exe";
 ConnectToEngine(a);
..}

void ConnectToEngine(WCHAR* path)
{...}

Comment: @nanosi Cool to know having been helpful. You might consider to self answer your question with an exact description of what you changed in the code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I am trying to open a file in Sublime Text through CreateProcess() but the build shows errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38076794/i-am-trying-to-open-a-file-in-sublime-text-through-createprocess-but-the-build)

Comment: Another dupe (this one is almost 1:1 copy): https://stackoverflow.com/q/53103443/7571258

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Argument of type "char \*" is incompatible with parameter of type "LPWSTR"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20611865/argument-of-type-char-is-incompatible-with-parameter-of-type-lpwstr)

Answer (score 0):

The Problem fixed with some notes from friends in above.
The working code is below:

```
    int main()
   {
    ...
    wchar_t a[] = L"stockfish.exe";
    ConnectToEngine(a);
    ...
   }


void ConnectToEngine(WCHAR* path)
{
    pipin_w = pipin_r = pipout_w = pipout_r = NULL;
    sats.nLength = sizeof(sats);
    sats.bInheritHandle = TRUE;
    sats.lpSecurityDescriptor = NULL;

    CreatePipe(&pipout_r, &pipout_w, &sats, 0);
    CreatePipe(&pipin_r, &pipin_w, &sats, 0);

    sti.dwFlags = STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW | STARTF_USESTDHANDLES;
    sti.wShowWindow = SW_HIDE;
    sti.hStdInput = pipin_r;
    sti.hStdOutput = pipout_w;
    sti.hStdError = pipout_w;

    CreateProcess(NULL, path, NULL, NULL, TRUE, 0, NULL, NULL, &sti, &pi);
}
```